# Reload UIScrollView by tapping a UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton

Let me explain my project first. I have some data in my `SQLIte` DB table called "note". 
In "note" table I have these fields: `id`, `noteToken`, `note`.

What I am doing here is load all the `note` in an `NSMUtableArray` from that table. And create `UIButton` according to that `array` content number and add those buttons in a `UIScrollView` as `subView`. The number of buttons and width of `scrollview` generate auto according to the number of content of that array. Now, when some one tap one of those Buttons, it will bring him to a next `viewController` and show him the corresponding note details in that `viewController`.

I do the same thing with another `NSMUtableArray`, but these time it read all the `id` from the "note" table. It equally generate new delete button in the same `UIScrollView`. But if some one tap on these delete button it will delete that particular note from the table "note" of `SQLIte` DB. **AND RELOAD THE `UIScrollView`**. All are done except the **RELOAD THE `UIScrollView` part**. This is what I want. I tried with all exist solution but don't know why it's not working.
Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.noteToken = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", fairId, exibitorId];

    scrollViewNoteWidth = 100;
    [scrollViewNote setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scrollViewNote setContentSize:CGSizeMake((noteButtonWidth * countNoteButtonArray) + scrollViewNoteWidth, 100)];

    sqLite = [[SQLite alloc] init];
    [self.sqLite callDataBaseAndNoteTableMethods];

    self.noteButtonArrayy = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    noteButtonArrayy = [self.sqLite returnDataFromNoteTable:noteToken];

    [self LoadNoteButtonAndDeleteButton:noteButtonArrayy];
}


//////////////*----------------------- Note Section (Down) -----------------------*//////////////
-(void) LoadNoteButtonAndDeleteButton:(NSMutableArray *) noteButtonArray
{
    sQLiteClass = [[SQLiteClass alloc] init];
    noteButtonArrayToShowNoteButton = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    /*--------------- Load the noteButton & pass note (Down)---------------*/
    for (int i = 0; i < [noteButtonArray count]; i++)
    {
        sQLiteClass = [noteButtonArray objectAtIndex:i];
        // NSString *ids = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", sQLiteClass.idNum];
        NSString *nt = sQLiteClass.note;
        [noteButtonArrayToShowNoteButton addObject:nt];
    }
    [self ShowNoteButtonMethod:noteButtonArrayToShowNoteButton];
    /*--------------- Load the noteButton & pass note (Up)---------------*/

    /*--------------- Load the deleteButton & pass id (Down)---------------*/
    noteButtonArrayToDeleteNoteButton = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < [noteButtonArray count]; i++)
    {
        sQLiteClass = [noteButtonArray objectAtIndex:i];
        // Convert int into NSString
        NSString *ids = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", sQLiteClass.idNum];
        [noteButtonArrayToDeleteNoteButton addObject:ids];
    }
    [self ShowNoteDeleteButtonMethod:noteButtonArrayToDeleteNoteButton];
    /*--------------- Load the deleteButton & pass id (Down)---------------*/
}

-(void) ShowNoteButtonMethod:(NSMutableArray *) btnarray
{
    countNoteButtonArray = [btnarray count];

    // For note button
    noteButtonWidth = 60;
    noteButtonXposition = 8;
    for (NSString *urls in btnarray)
    {
        noteButtonXposition = [self addNoteButton:noteButtonXposition AndURL:urls];
    }
}

-(int) addNoteButton:(int) xposition AndURL:(NSString *) urls
{
    noteButton =[ButtonClass buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    noteButton.frame = CGRectMake(noteButtonXposition, 8.0, noteButtonWidth, 60.0);
    [noteButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"note.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [noteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(tapOnNoteButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [noteButton setUrl:urls];
    noteButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.scrollViewNote addSubview:noteButton];
    noteButtonXposition = noteButtonXposition + noteButtonWidth + 18;

    return noteButtonXposition;
}

-(void)tapOnNoteButton:(ButtonClass*)sender
{
    urlNote = sender.url;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToNoteDetailsViewController" sender:urlNote];
}

-(void) ShowNoteDeleteButtonMethod:(NSMutableArray *) btnarray
{
    countNoteButtonArray = [btnarray count];

    // For delete button
    deleteNoteButtonWidth = 14;
    deleteNoteButtonXposition = 31;
    for (NSString *idNumber in btnarray)
    {
        deleteNoteButtonXposition = [self addDeleteButton:deleteNoteButtonXposition AndURL:idNumber];
    }
}

-(int) addDeleteButton:(int) xposition AndURL:(NSString *) idNumber
{
    deleteNoteButton =[ButtonClass buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    deleteNoteButton.frame = CGRectMake(deleteNoteButtonXposition, 74.0, deleteNoteButtonWidth, 20.0);
    [deleteNoteButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"delete.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [deleteNoteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(tapOnDeleteButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [deleteNoteButton setIdNum:idNumber];
    deleteNoteButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.scrollViewNote addSubview:deleteNoteButton];
    deleteNoteButtonXposition = deleteNoteButtonXposition + deleteNoteButtonWidth + 65;

    return deleteNoteButtonXposition;
}

-(void)tapOnDeleteButton:(ButtonClass*)sender
{
    idNumb = sender.idNum;
    [self.sqLite deleteData:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM note WHERE id IS '%@'", idNumb]];
    // NSLog(@"idNumb %@", idNumb);

    //[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
    //[self.view setNeedsLayout];
    //[self LoadNoteButtonAndDeleteButton];
    //[self viewDidLoad];

//    if ([self isViewLoaded])
//    {
//        //self.view = Nil;
//        //[self viewDidLoad];
//        [self LoadNoteButtonAndDeleteButton];
//    }
}
//////////////*----------------------- Note Section (Up) -----------------------*//////////////

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"goToNoteDetailsViewController"])
    {
        NoteDetailsViewController *noteDetailsViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        [noteDetailsViewController setUrl:sender];
    }
}
```

Here's the screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we can feel the difference between `UIScrollView` and `UICollectionView`, however `UICollectionView` is made up of `UIScrollView`, `UICollectionView` can be reload and adjust its content accordingly, where `UIScrollView` can't.

Ok, now in your case, you've to reload (refresh) your scroll view, which is not possible as we can with `UICollectionView` or `UITableView`.

You've two options,

Best option (little tough) : replace `UIScrollView` with `UICollectionView` - will take some of your time, but better for reducing code complexity and good performance of your app.

Poor option (easy) : Stay as it with `UIScrollView` - when you want to reload, delete each subview from it, and then again show and load everything. Highly not recommended.

IMHO, you should go with best option.

Comment: I have chosen your "Best option" & it is working perfectly now as I wanted. It's simpler, faster & cool. :)
Thanks for the comment. Stay well. :)